# SQL Server Group By Query Select first row each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do this query. This is what I have.

My table is: Table

```
StudyID FacultyID Year    Access1   Access2    Access3
1          1       2014       4        8          5
1          2       2014       8        4          7
1          1       2013       5        4          4
2          3       2014       4        6          5
2          5       2013       5        8         10
2          4       2014       5        5          7
3          7       2013       9        4          7
```

I want to group by StudyID and Year and get the minimum value of each field Access1 Access2 and Access3 and show only the last year, I mean for each group the first row.
Here is the Result.

```
StudyID  Year    Access1   Access2    Access3
1        2014       4        4          5
2        2014       4        5          5
3        2013       9        4          7
```

This is my Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.StudyID, T.Year, MIN(T.Access1), MIN(T.Access2), MIN(T.Access3)
FROM T
GROUP BY T.StudyID, T.Year
ORDER BY T.StudyID, T.Year DESC
```

I also tried with this one.

```
 ;WITH MyQuery AS (     SELECT DISTINCT T.StudyID, T.Year, MIN(T.Access1), MIN(T.Access2), MIN(T.Access3),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.StudyID, T.Year ORDER BY T.StudyID, T.Year DESC) AS rownumber
    FROM T  GROUP BY T.StudyID, T.Year      ORDER BY T.StudyID , T.Year DESC ) SELECT * FROM MyQuery WHERE rownumber = 1
```

Any success, I know I am missing something...but dont know what?
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Change your group by, on your query from `GROUP BY EF.EstudioID, NC.Anyo` to `GROUP BY T.StudyID, T.Year `

Comment: I'd add in HAVING Max(Year) to the end there.

Comment: Thats not allow in SQL server :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY StudyID, Year` and then in an outer query select the first row from each `StudyID, Year` group:

```
SELECT StudyID, Year, minAccess1, minAccess2, minAccess3
FROM (
   SELECT StudyID, Year, min(Access1) minAccess1, min(Access2) minAccess2,
          min(Access3) minAccess3, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudyID ORDER BY Year DESC) AS rn 
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY StudyID, Year ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER` is used to assign an ordering number to each `StudyID` group according to `Year` values. The row with the maximum `Year` value is assigned a `rn = 1`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was doing it that way but did something wrong. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.StudyID, T.Year, MIN(T.Access1), MIN(T.Access2), MIN(T.Access3)
FROM myTable T
WHERE T.Year = (SELECT MAX(T2.Year) FROM myTable T2 WHERE T2.StudyID = T.StudyID)
GROUP BY T.StudyID
```

Its giving the result you wanted in SQLite, but perhaps in SQL-Server needs some alias I'm not sure. Can't test it right now.

Comment: I think you'll need to add T.Year to the GROUP BY list.

Comment: the group by should be `T.StudyID, T.Year` and the DISTINCT clause is unnecessary. The group by on sqlserver will be mandatory in this case

Comment: The distinct clause isn't unnecesary, it will do the same job as grouping by year in this case.

Comment: when using GROUP BY, distinct is 100 % redundant. It is not possible to get duplicate rows when using GROUP BY

Comment: @t-clausen.dk But I wasn't grouping by year, so if there were 2 years with the same year = MAx(year), it will generate 2 exactly equal rows. It is true though, that sql server won't admit that query because Year isn't grouped nor MAXed, MINed or SUMed, but SQLite does, and works.

Answer (score 0):

This is giving the answer you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.StudyID, T.Year, MIN(T.Access1) as Access1, MIN(T.Access2) as Access2, MIN(T.Access3) as Access3
FROM T T
WHERE T.Year = (SELECT MAX(T2.Year) FROM T T2 WHERE StudyID = T.StudyID)
GROUP BY T.StudyID, T.Year
Order by 1
```

Comment: I dont have the 50 reputation to comment on Pinx0, I just modified his query and posted as a separate post